# Mitochondrial diseases inheritance

Tags: genetics, mitochondria

I've read information about mito genes inheritance but some parts are still obscure for me.

Here is the context:
Mother has a son that is affected by some mitochondrial disease and a healthy daughter. So I suppose that mother is carrier of the recessive mutated gene which she passed to him, right? Articles in the internet tell that mito genes are always inherited from a female ([link](https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3757997)), but some also tell that two carriers are needed in order to child be possibly affected (["How is mitochondrial disease inherited?" section](https://mitochondrialdiseasenews.com/2020/04/14/faqs-about-mitochondrial-disease/)). But this is controversy, isn't it?

My question is:
Can daughter be also a carrier of this mutated gene? If yes, what conditions should be met in order to her to create an affected child?

Can someone please explain me this?

Comment: We can't do personal medical advice here for you or your sister. We can, however, help you to understand mitochondrial inheritance. Please refer to the specific sources you're reading (rather than "articles in the internet"), and depersonalize your question a bit to ask about mitochondrial disease inheritance rather than your family so it can be acceptable here.

Comment: @BryanKrause I am not asking personal medical advises but about general inheritance mechanism. Here is one of the articles: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3757997/ "Mitochondrial Biology and Genetics" section. However, this specific one as far as I see doesn't tell about two carriers.

Comment: Actually you *are* asking for personal medical advice: whether your mother is a carrier is a personal medical advice question, whether your sister is a carrier and should be worried about possible children is a personal medical advice question.

Comment: You write in your question "Articles in the internet tell that mito genes are always inherited from a female" - you should have a specific source for this (rather than "articles in the internet"), and reference that source in your question (not a comment). "two carriers are needed in order to child be possibly affected" - you should have a specific source for this, and reference that source in your question. Referencing these sources will help answerers help you interpret what you're reading.

Comment: @BryanKrause I am working on it

Comment: Your second link is from a content farm website, effectively a scam for search engine traffic. Do not rely on websites like this for information.

Comment: @BryanKrause Ok, thank you. But what about the first one? It tells that mutated mitochondria number must be larger than some threshold in order to individual be affected. Is it easy for a newborn to pass this threshold when their mother already have some of these genes?